# Pulling Previous Project Versions From Github in Android Studio

Tags: android, git

I'm new to GitHub. All of the tutorials that I have watched deal with uploading and downloading projects from GitHub. My question is let's say that I commit a project in android studio (Version 1). I then go on and add a number of methods to a class and commit that (Version 2). I then realize that my first version was more efficient. How can I pull and open version 1 from GitHub in android studio and work with that? Any helpful links would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to pull anything from GitHub. You have the complete history of the repository locally available. That is the point with a DVCS.

Just checkout the old version if you want to look at it in the working tree.

Use revert if you want to undo version 2 in a new commit 3.

Use reset or interactive rebase if you want to completely discard the version 2 commit, but be aware that this will rewrite published history if you did push version 2 already and anyone else that already fetched your change will have to fix their local branches after you messed with already pushed history.

Comment: I'm sorry where are all of these options? Are they in Android Studio?

Comment: I'm not sure how tight the integration into AS is, but as those are pretty basic Git functions, I'd guess yes. If not, you can still use the command-line or a different Git GUI to do it.